# Is it possible to predefine smart contracts in genesis.json?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, go-ethereum

I encountered exactly the same issue as this https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7707/is-it-possible-to-preload-contracts-in-the-genesis-block?rq=1

Agian, is it possible to predefine a contract by assigning alloc -> code field like this,

[image]

However, it seems like no matter which method in the contract I call, it always returns the Bytecode of the contract itself regardless of the logic and content of this method.

[image]

And this might be the reason when I deploy a contract:

[image]

When I call test(), obtaining:

[image]
which is not a string.

When I call test2(), obtaining:

[image]
which is a very big number.

When I call test3(1), obtaining a false,
which is not 1 == 1.

I have taken a look through the related threads, found this, https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/30366/how-does-the-genesis-json-file-define-the-initial-state-of-the-blockchain

It looks like the storage setting is necessary but I have totally no idea what key/value I should write.

How could I deal with this case then?

Comment: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7707/is-it-possible-to-preload-contracts-in-the-genesis-block/121579#121579

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> However, it seems like no matter which method in the contract I call, it always returns the Bytecode of the contract itself regardless of the logic and content of this method.

This sounds to me like you included `--bin` instead of `--bin-runtime` from `solc`

How did you generate the `code` to be included?

The `--bin` code is the code that is run *on the contract creation transaction*, which returns the actual code to be included in the contract (which is `--bin-runtime`).

Comment: bytecode is generated via the Remix IDE. So you mean the bytecode generated in the first place is not the one actually stored in the statedb.Code/CodeHash? As such how could I get the code meant to be included in the contract?

Comment: sorry, i mean *to be included in the blockchain

Comment: solved by using solc --bin-runtime..Thx so much again.

Comment: @SaberYu Glad it helped. Please mark the answer as correct